# php curl follow redirects?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, curl, redirect

I have a page that is meant to receive a curl request from another server.

I need to format this curl request to another format.

so I have this code

```
<?php
$id =     (isset($_GET['msgid'])    ? $_GET['msgid']   : 'null');
$from =   (isset($_GET['from'])     ? $_GET['from']    : 'null');
$body =   (isset($_GET['content'])  ? $_GET['content'] : 'null');
$status = (isset($_GET['status'])   ? $_GET['status']  : 'null');

header("location: ../action/receive_message/$id/$from/$body/$status");
?>
```

so, if someone was to launch a curl request to
http://example.com/intercept/test.php?id=123&from=me&body=something;

Will that call
http://example.com/action/123/me/something/null?

Or if not is there a way i can get it to?

The other one is.

Is there a way I can do this in .htaccess?
So I dont have to create a seperate file for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl doesn't follow redirects by default.

If you're running curl from the command line, you need to add the `-L` flag to your command to make it follow redirects.

If you're calling curl via a library, you need to set the `FOLLOWLOCATION` curl option to true (or 1), and the exact code to do that will depend on the language/library/wrapper you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think your code has some issues as you are setting those variables to the result of `isset()`, which is true or false.  Also, setting null for the string when you are including it later is a bad plan, if you want the word null to appear use `'null'`, if nothing then use the empty string.

That should be:

```
$id =     (isset($_GET['msgid'])    ? $_GET['msgid']   : '');
$from =   (isset($_GET['from'])     ? $_GET['from']    : '');
$body =   (isset($_GET['content'])  ? $_GET['content'] : '');
$status = (isset($_GET['status'])   ? $_GET['status']  : '');
```

The `Location` header will tell curl to redirect, which curl will do if given the `-L` option when called.  Note that `Location` does not support relative URLs, you need to specify the full URL I believe.

Yes, you can do that using `mod_rewrite` in the file `/intercept/.htaccess` providing the query string is in the right order and all values are present, it is possible to handle with random order or missing entries, but more complex.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /intercept/

# Note, & may need escaping, can not recall
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+)&from=([^&]+)&content=([^&]+)&status=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule test.php /action/%1/%2/%3/%4 [L]
```

If on the same site, you can use the `[L]` otherwise specify the full URL and use `[R]` instead.

Comment: With regards to the htaccess, The url that they will point to is 
http://example.com/receive_message?...
the url it needs to be rewritten to is
http://example.com/action/receive_message/id/from/body/status

The message could contain one, none, some, or all of the $_GET's if it does not exists it should be replaced with null (literally 'null' not '' as the receiving function reads that)

Comment: If you are locally redirecting with a variable (as in non-constant) query string, I would recommend using the PHP script to do it, as it will be complicated to do it using the rewrite.  Remember to make the URL absolute in the `header()` and call `exit()` after it.